# Heroku+Django - failed to find application

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm having problems getting my Django app to work on Heroku, when I try to access the site I get an error in the log saying: "Failed to find application HomeP" right after "starting process with command gunicorn HomeP:app" which is the command I've entered in Procfile

Now I'm really new to both Python, Django and Heroku and I'm on a windows machine running Python for Visual Studio, so I'm a bit lost on how the directory structure should be in order for Heroku to work. This seems to be related to gunicorn which Im not able to test on windows.

My directory structure is basically a root folder with Procfile and manage.py
Below this folder there's a HomeP folder (containing settings.py etc) and a Ins folder (containing most of my view, models etc)

Any help appreciated!